# Error while installing Sitecore package with File in Docker/AKS Sitecore

Tags: docker, aks

I am getting error while installing a file package.But getting error:

```
The installation failed.
Background process failed: Access to the path is denied.
For more information see the Sitecore log.
Try one of the following options:
Retry the installation
```

I already refered some blogs and used the command to privide permission on whole inetpub folder but seems its not working. Below is the code section from my cm docker file

```
 **RUN icacls 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot' /grant 'IIS_IUSRS:(F)'**
WORKDIR C:\inetpub\wwwroot
COPY --from=solution c:\artifacts\website .
```

Please suggest how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: You can check log file to get more details. Also what does your package contain, Files or Items ? When does this error occur ? Any specific item/file ? Try breaking your package into smaller ones to find out which file/items is causing the trouble..

Comment: Its a docker specific permission issue. Nothing to do with Size. Package contains a small single file.

Comment: Please share your logs in the post to understand the issue better.

Comment: AFAIK, updating the permission and installing the package via admin in a docker environment might be considered as a workaround for a local environment. Consider including the package as part of your build step or sync the package content using SCS or Unicorn and deploy the assemblies and other files using Volumes and Sitecore containers have deployment scripts to copy it to the destination folder.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for your inputs. I'll have a look.

Comment: @Sitecoredev Try this solution. Most probably this should work. https://www.koenheye.be/sitecore-docker-install-packages-in-cm-environment/